# How to most efficiently store possible combinations of categories?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, optimization

I have a table of categories (currently with 14 rows, not likely to change). A need to cache combinations of categories emerged, so I'm creating a table of allowed combinations (only few hundreds of the ~10^10 combinations are likely to be ever searched for and I can constraint it even more). However, I'm not sure how to implement it.

Combination of 14 columns for each row in the `category` table looks simple, but it doesn't feel right. Any change in the `category` data would make a change in the `combination` table structure necessary.

Another option was to make the `combination` only with ID and combination name and store the important information in the `category_combination` join table. This feels "right", but making sure that each combination is unique becomes a non-trivial task (unlike simple applying unique constraint over a group of columns in the former case). In PostgreSQL, I would make a deferred trigger, but this is not possible in MySQL. The best option I can think of with MySQL is to make it a function and then calling it from the client app; if it finds a dupe, I'd cancel the transaction. I would aggregate the categories in the combination with `GROUP_CONCAT` (ordered, of course), either in the query or in an auxiliary view, and then compare the arrays.

Still, I'm not sure if there's no more elegant way, either a completely different approach, or an optimization of the second approach. How to do it best?

EDIT: category combinations will be often used in search, so it needs to be optimized for searching. Adding new a combination will be rare and I hope we will avoid adding new categories, though this should still be possible (even with a lot of work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the `SET` datatype.  With that, you could represent all combinations of 14 categories in 14 bits (2 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

I realized one thing: I can easily obtain the `ID` of the combination by other means, so what I need most now is to obtain the array of categories, which is best done by the `SET` approach suggested by [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98600/22006). However, I don't want to delete this my answer, because it best answers the question as written (especially the EDIT in the question). It's below.

---

I decided to pick my approach 1, the 14 int(1) columns. Why I think it's most efficient in my case:

- I hope I will avoid adding new categories, so making a new column is not such a big problem. The second ("join table") approach would handle this seamlessly on database level, but I would still need to change my client app, so this is a marginal gain.
- `int(1)` is not PostgreSQL's `boolean`, which is one bit, but still it's not so much bigger than the `SET` approach
- adding new combinations is easy; in my second approach, I would need to insert into several tables
- 14 rows is not so much, definitely not enough for some [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)-like approach
- maintaining uniqueness is easy both in this and the `SET` approach, unlike the join table one
- 14 ORs or ANDs per query is a lot, but still manageable
- the `SET` approach allow for `FIND_IN_SET` search; however, searches based on `SELECT` with many ORs in the `WHERE` part are several orders of magnitude faster with proper indexes
- I'm not sure about searching with the join table approach. Dynamic `SELECT`s constructed in the client can't find a single row, `SELECT` with many ORs is possible, and the `GROUP_CONCAT` approach I originally thought about would ignore the indexes. Perhaps there's something more elegant I don't know about, but I don't expect it to be more efficient than the OR search.

Comment: `int(1)` is 4 bytes. You probably want to use `tinyint` (1 byte) instead.