# How to make an indexed search over a list (set)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

A follow-up question for [How to most efficiently store possible combinations of categories?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/98523/22006)

An [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98600/22006) pointed to `SET` datatype. As far as I know, the default search option for it, F[IND_IN_SET, doesn't support indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945341/1801588). The other issues (redundancy due to violating 1NF) are negligible for me, but I will need to use the data in a search quite often, so I can't use SET unless I can optimize the query somehow, probably by some index. Is it possible?

I'm using MySQL 5.5 (InnoDB). In 5.6+ there is something called [fulltext index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) - I'm not sure it's useful in this case, but even if it does, it's not applicable in my case.